# Combine two array in php

Tags: php, for-loop, foreach

I have two array in php and now I want to  combine this two array as below.

```
$a1 = Array(
    'ansid4' => 4,
    'ansid5' => 5,
    'ansid6' => 6
);

$a2 = Array(
    'value' => 'demo',
    'value2' => 'demo2'
);
```

**Required Output:**

```
$target = Array(
    4 => 'demo',
    5 => 'demo2',
    6 => Null
);
```

Thanks in advance

Comment: take a look at [array-count-values](http://php.net/manual/en/function.array-count-values.php) and [array-merge](http://php.net/manual/en/function.array-merge.php)

Comment: that second array is invalid, array keys must be unique

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
$resultArray = array();

while ($key = array_pop($arrayOne)) {
  $resultArray[$key] = array_pop($arrayTwo);
}
```

or you could do

```
$resultArray = array();

foreach ($arrayOne as $key) {
  $resultArray[$key] = array_shift($arrayTwo);
}
```

Both solutions have the disadvantage that they consume one or both arrays.
If you need them still after the combination you could make copies of the Arrays and have those consumed.

Answer (score 0):

Take a look at [array_combine](http://php.net/manual/en/function.array-combine.php)
you can send to this function array of keys and array of values and it return assoc array

please notice that the two arrays must have the same number of elements.
if you cant take care of that, try using [array_pad](http://php.net/manual/en/function.array-pad.php) before

Answer (score 0):

```
$targetArray = array('a'=>'','b'=>''); 
$sourceArray = array('a'=>array(1,2,3),'c'=>'c','d'=>'d');
$result = array_merge( $targetArray, $sourceArray);
$array_text = recurse_array($result);
echo $array_text;

function recurse_array($values){
    $content = '';
    if( is_array($values) ){
        foreach($values as $key => $value){
            if( is_array($value) ){
                $content.="$key<br />".recurse_array($value);
            }else{
                $content.="$key = $value<br />";
            }

        }
    }
    return $content;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You have to have the same number of elements in both arrays so we start with counting of elements and add necessary NULL values by [`array_pad`](http://php.net/manual/en/function.array-pad.php)

```
if (count($a1) > count($a2))
{
    $a2 = array_pad1($a2, count($a1), NULL);
}
elseif (count($a1) < count($a2))
{
    $a1 = array_pad($a1, count($a2), NULL);
}
```

Then we use [`array_combine`](http://php.net/manual/en/function.array-combine.php), which creates new array. From both arrays we use values by [`array_values`](http://php.net/manual/en/function.array-values.php). From first array we use values as keys and from second array we use values as values:-)

```
$target = array_combine(array_values($a1), array_values($a2))
```